# Argo CD Application metrics

Tags: kubernetes, devops, monitoring, argocd

Does Argo CD return metrics such as target version?
The bottom line is that for each application object in 2 different clusters, we would like to compare versions of all entities described in the application manifest. And if there are any differences, send an alert about the inconsistency of the clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several built-in metrics in ArgoCD which can help you to monitor your applications and also the target version of each resource in the kubernetes cluster and it will be shown in Prometheus format.

ArgoCD exposes metrics in [Prometheus format](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/), which can be scraped and visualized using a variety of monitoring tools.

By collecting metrics from the clusters you can identify the differences in the target version and you can use [Prometheus Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) to automate the alerts.